# Calculate the subgradient at $\pm \sqrt{2}$ for $1/2 x^2$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

Let $f(x) = (1/2) x^2, x \in [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$ and $f(x) = +\infty$ elsewhere

I would like to compute the subgradient of this function at the boundary $\pm\sqrt2$. However, I am not sure how to proceed.

Here is my attempt:

$\partial f(x) = \{g \in \mathbb{R}| (1/2) y^2 \geq (1/2) x^2 + g(y - x), \forall y \in [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]\}$

Therefore,
$\partial f(\sqrt{2} ) = \{g \in \mathbb{R} | (1/2) y^2 \geq 1 + g(y - \sqrt{2}), \forall  y \in  [-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]\}$

Solving for $g$ requires me to solve that quadratic, which looks a bit complicated. So I test some values of $y$.

Let $y = \sqrt{2}$, then $1 \geq 1 + g(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2})$ or $g \in [-\infty, \infty]$.

Let $y = -\sqrt{2}$, then $1 \geq 1 + g(-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2})$ or $g \geq 0$.

Does this mean that the subgradient of this function at $\sqrt{2}$ is $g  \in [0, \infty]$? It does not make sense when looking at the graph.

Update: there was some typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ from the left at $x=\sqrt{2}$ is just the derivative of $h(x)=x^2/2$ at that point, that is, $f'_-(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$. The derivative from the right is $+\infty$, given that the function jumps to infinity. Therefore, your subdifferential is the set $\partial f(\sqrt{2})=[\sqrt{2},+\infty)$. Your function is even, so $\partial f(-\sqrt{2})=[-\infty,-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought so as much. But I don't quite understand the following: since $f^\prime(x)$ has a domain $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$. And we know that the subgradient is equal to the gradient at interior points (points where $f$ is differentiable). Why is the derivative still valid at the boundary and equal to the subgradient?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189152/differentiability-on-the-boundary

Comment: I believe your domain is the closed interval $[-\sqrt{2},+\sqrt{2}]$. The property you mentioned about interior points is also valid for boundary points as long as your function is continuous there (from the corresponding side). It is also the case that the sub gradient is the interval $[f'_-(a),f'_+(a)]$ or $[f'_-(a),+\infty)$ or $(-\infty, f'_+(a)]$ depending on whether $a$ is interior or is a boundary point.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo substituting $x=\sqrt2$; your inequality should be
$$
\frac12 y^2 \ge 1 + g(y-\sqrt2).
$$
for all $y\in [-\sqrt2, \sqrt2]$. For $y$ outside this interval, there is no restriction since $f(y)=\infty$ there. Solving for $g$ is easy, not a quadratic:
$$
g \ge \frac{\frac12 y^2-1}{y-\sqrt2} = \frac{y+\sqrt2}{2},
$$
which attains it's supremum when $y\to \sqrt2$ (it needs to hold for all $y$ in the interval, so we look for the $y$ that forces $g$ to be largest), so $g\ge \sqrt2$. So the subgradient is $[\sqrt2, \infty)$.

You should be able to repeat this process for $x=-\sqrt2$ now. Note that the answer could be found easier using regular derivatives, since the lower bound on $g$ is equal to
$$
\lim_{y\to(\sqrt2)^-}\frac{f(y)-f(\sqrt2)}{y-\sqrt2}
= \frac{d}{dy}\frac12y^2 \bigg|_{y=\sqrt2} = \sqrt2 .
$$

NOTE: The mistake in your attempt was that you only inserted two particular values of $y$ in the inequality. You need it to hold for *all* values of $y$, and since $f$ is convex, the most restricting $y$-values will be in limit as $y\to (\sqrt2)^-$ (which leads us back to the derivative).